# Can directory listings appear in different languages with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localization, region, directory-listing

I have set up a simple site for a design client at **pub.regularsite.com** where I put finished design projects.

The site is set using Apache directory listings with subdirectories for logos, flyers etc.

The problem is that the listing headers (**name, last modified & size** are in English and **I would like them to appear in French**.

**Is it possible to specify the header language in the .htaccess file or elsewhere?**

**Is it possible to make it automatic, based on the user's system language?**

Comment: It would be nice if people who downvote would explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think you can do this with the default directory-listing module that ships with Apache.

By default, directory listings are generated by Apache's mod_autoindex, which according to the latest version in the repository [1] does not have any translations for strings such as "Last modified" etc.

If you don't care about it being in the user's preferred language and just be in French all the time, I'm guessing that if you translate all the strings in that file, recompile the module, reinstall it and restart Apache, it'll do what you want -- although it's probably more work than finding some other directory generation tool out there with support for translations on a per-user basis.

[1] See http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/generators/mod_autoindex.c?revision=1705983&view=markup at line 1584: the "Last modified" string is hardcoded, does not refer to a dictionary of translations.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that error pages can be made language-specific and I was hoping that the same thing would be true for directory listings.

Comment: I had a thought... if it's possible, I should be able to find an example: http://damien.floriani.pagesperso-orange.fr/Caml/TD/index.htm, but it appears to be the only site on the internet that does this.

Comment: It's definitely possible either by building your own index page generator, or by tweaking the source code as indicated in my answer. It's just not something you can configure out of the box. Regarding the example you gave on pagesperso-orange.fr, it doesn't look like it's generated using Apache's mod_autoindex -- it has a "meta" tag indicating that it was generated using MSHTML, which Apache's mod_autoindex would not output.